# Trying to get property of non-object in laravel shopping cart

Tags: laravel

I am using darryldecode for shopping cart in my project

this is my shoppingcartController and add method:

```
public function add(){

        $pdt = Singleproduct::find(\request()->id);

        \Cart::add(array(
            array(
                'id' => $pdt->id,
                'name' => $pdt->name ,
                'price' => $pdt->price,
                'quantity' => \request()->qty ,
                'attributes' => array()
            )));

    }
```

and this is route list:

```
Route::post('/cart/add'  ,  'admin\ShopingController@add')->name('cart.add');
```

and in my SingleProduct i have id,price and name!

the error is:"Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

where is the problem??

Comment: First:check request.i think its empty.maybe you need to pass it as arguement of function and after that use it.Second:check object with this property exist in your table.use dd()in each level.

Comment: Actually you are not getting value in `\request()->id`

Comment: I can't undrestant,which value I should get?

Answer (score 1):

The `id` may be returning null, or you may not be getting the right `request` object.  Try injecting it into the method (which is kind of a 'Laravel') way to do it:

```
public function add(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){

    $pdt = Singleproduct::find($request->input('id'));

}
```

Dump the request variable if you want to double check it has the `id` from your form:  `dd($request->all());`  If `id` is not there in the dump, you can see where your problem lies.

Comment: I use your code and it return null!maybe it's the problem

Comment: Yes, if you used this and got null, you have your answer.

Comment: Actully my question is how to solve the problem,now I should do what?